# Storing a key in SRAM in an embedded device

Tags: encryption, embedded-system

I'm working on an embedded device which need to decrypt a file in USB stick using a secret key. I read many questions about storing a key in embedded device and found that it's secure to store a key in a volatile memory such as SRAM.

My idea is to use a function to calculate the key from a random string (like sha256("strawbery")) and use the result as a secret to decrypt my file in USB stick. This way, the key is only store in SRAM and it's difficult to reverse engineer and understand what my function does with the random string.

I know that there is no way to perfectly store a key in an offline-embedded device but my goal is to extend the time it takes to crack the key.

So can you suggest a function to calculate the key like sha256 or any other method to store a key (let's assume that the hacker can only do reverse-engineer my software but cannot read the value in SRAM)

Comment: How is the key provisioned (and why not just use random bits)? You do realise SRAM is not a persistent memory? How do you handle keys after power failure?

Comment: @domen because I only need the key in a short period to decrypt a file in USB stick so I don't need to store it somewhere else. My idea is hardcode a simple string in code, example "strawberry" and use a complex function to generate the final key from this simple string. So when reverse engineer, it take time to understand what my function do, it's all the objectif

Comment: @Lala if it's an embedded device, who are you trying to hide the data from?   Most MCUs do not have an encryption core, so you'd have the data raw in memory anyway.  I can just use JTAG to dump it.

Comment: You have a hardcoded "strawberry" and algorithm. You worry about derived key being leaked, and you're assuming it's hard to reverse engineer your code. Have you considered an attack where the key generation code just gets run (either on actual hardware or simulated)? I know that what I'd do. And if you say physical security mitigates this, then why do you bother deriving the key in the first place? I'd rethink the design, keeping in mind what the actual attack vectors are (as @bdegnan asks).

Comment: @domen thanks for your help, I see my problem here.